# to store phone number in sqlite for call blocking application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, callblocking

i am working on call blocking application for android 2.1, for this i used sqlite database to store the phone number, i am using TEXT to store the phone number.i have some question in my mind.

1: what is the correct data type for column phone number.

2: is there any solution for call blocking for android above 2.2

because this is only working on 2.1 and below it.

Comment: Since you are asking two different questions, it's better to actually post them as separate questions on this site.

Comment: ok . plz share with me that you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this link .You got the idea about sqlite. In call blocking application you have to use you can use INTEGER is better i think

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html